# Org-mode export to Latex: page break at each section and subsection

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I want the pdf document to always have a page break at a section and subsection. I could add

> #+latex: \clearpage

before each heading and sub-heading on org-mode. However, I think it makes my org document kind of confusing and visually dirty.

Is there a way to do it all at once, i.e., to force a page break so that all sections and subsections begin always on a new page?

I'd be glad if anyone help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \let\oldsection\section
#+LATEX_HEADER: \renewcommand{\section}{\clearpage\oldsection}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \let\oldsubsection\subsection
#+LATEX_HEADER: \renewcommand{\subsection}{\clearpage\oldsubsection}
```

Comment: I'm not using Latex though, but Org-mode, and exporting it to latex. Your solution work if I export to latex and then edit the latex code every time I export it. I'd rather like a code that I could write on org-mode itself.

Comment: @RhythmicalDiphthong I modified the answer according to manual https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-export.html

Comment: It worked well. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

You could add

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\newcommand{\subsectionbreak}{\clearpage}
```

to your header. This has the advantage that it will automatically check if the previous unit actually had content and only add a page break in this case. This means that a section directly followed by a subsection won't be split across empty pages.